# Textarea editable except values from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, textarea

I have two `input` fields and one `textarea`. When I type something in the `input` fields their `.val()` are automatically added to the `textarea`.

It is working fine, but I want these values in the `textarea` as read-only.

I want the textarea to behave like this:
I could type extra text but can't delete the text which is obtained from two `input` fields.

```js
$(function() {
  var text1 = $('#text1');
  var text2 = $('#text2');
  var description = $('#description');

  function onChange() {
    description.val("Chesis No:  " + text1.val() + ", Engine No:  " + text2.val());

    var base = description.val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + base, "i");
    $('#description').on("input", function(ev) {
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (!regex.test(query)) {
        //ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(base);
      }
    });
  }

  $('#text1')
    .change(onChange)
    .keyup(onChange);

  $('#text2')
    .change(onChange)
    .keyup(onChange);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Chassis No" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="Engine No " class="form-control" />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="postContent" id="description"></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dreamfighterr/x4v0sxt8/

Comment: You cannot have a partially-editable field. It's either editable or it's not. If you want this behaviour, allow the user to type the notes in a separate field, then combine the values before submitting the form.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dreamfighterr/L3n81298/ It is working already, but when I pass a input value (not a string) its failed

Comment: ... and then I disable Javascript and delete that text and break your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**
*Using only one `textarea`*

I played a little more with your code and ended-up with this really easy solution:

- Split all the lines of the `textarea`,
- Put the values of the inputs in the first line (That simulates the "read-only" for this line)
- Join back all the lines.

Here is a working snippet:
(See comments in my code)

```js
$(function() {
  var text1 = $('#text1');
  var text2 = $('#text2');
  var description = $('#description');

  // TAKIT: Changed all in this function
  function onChange() {
    var desc = description.val().split('\n');
    
    // TAKIT: Modified here
    var texts = []; // TAKIT: Added an array to make it easier
    if (text1.val())  texts.push("Chesis No: " + text1.val());
    if (text2.val())  texts.push("Engine No: " + text2.val());
    desc[0] = texts.join(', ');
    
    if (desc.length == 1) desc[1] = '';
    description.val(desc.join('\n'));
  }

  // TAKIT: Suggestion to simplify
  $('.form-control').on('keyup change', onChange);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Chassis No" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="Engine No" class="form-control" />
<br><br>
<textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="postContent" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

I think it can't be easier!

Hope it helps.

⋅
⋅
⋅

---

**Old answer**
*Adding a new `textarea`*

As you can't have a "partially-read-only" element, I suggest you that approch instead:

- Add a new `textarea` element which `id="text3"`,
- Simplify your code using `$('[id^="text"]')` to select all elements which id starts with “text”,
- Add `readonly` attribute on the `#description` `textarea` that merges the text from the input elements.

That way, the resulting content in `#description` will be accessible to select/copy/paste, but would not be modifiable.

Working snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var text1 = $('#text1');
  var text2 = $('#text2');
  var text3 = $('#text3'); // TAKIT: Added
  var description = $('#description');

  function onChange() {
    description.val("Chesis No:  " + text1.val() + ", Engine No:  " + text2.val() + '\n' + text3.val()); // TAKIT: Added

    var base = description.val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + base, "i");
    $('#description').on("input", function(ev) {
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (!regex.test(query)) {
        //ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(base);
      }
    });
  }

  // TAKIT: Suggestion to simplify
  $('[id^="text"]')
    .change(onChange)
    .keyup(onChange);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Chassis No" class="form-control" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="Engine No " class="form-control" />
<br>
<textarea id="text3" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
<br><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="postContent" id="description" readonly></textarea>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello again, Can you please help me to modify the code a bit. I dont want the dashed line or new line, I want to add extra character only a space after the un-editable content. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the two inputs value and instead of directly insert them to the text area , you will create two strings and every time the user change any input append the input file the one of the strings then append that string to your text area , see the example below , as you can see I use the **blur** event instead of **change** to get the whole value of changed input

see the complete example to understand the solution

```js
$(function() {
  var firstString ='';
  var secondString = '';
  var text1 = $('#text1');
  var text2 = $('#text2');
  var description = $('#description');

  function onChange() {
    description.val("Chesis No:  " + text1.val() + ", Engine No:  " + text2.val());

    var base = description.val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + base, "i");
    $('#description').on("input", function(ev) {
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (!regex.test(query)) {
        //ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(base);
      }
    });
  }
function ontext1Blur(){
  firstString+=text1.val()
 description.val("Chesis No:  " + firstString + ", Engine No:  " + text2.val());
 var base = description.val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + base, "i");
    $('#description').on("input", function(ev) {
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (!regex.test(query)) {
        //ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(base);
      }
    });
}
function ontext2Blur(){
  secondString+=text2.val()
 description.val("Chesis No:  " + firstString + ", Engine No:  " + secondString);
 var base = description.val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + base, "i");
    $('#description').on("input", function(ev) {
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (!regex.test(query)) {
        //ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(base);
      }
    });
}
  $('#text1')
    .blur(ontext1Blur)

  $('#text2')
    .blur(ontext2Blur);

});
```

```css
textarea {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Chassis No" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="Engine No " class="form-control" />
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50" name="postContent" id="description"></textarea>
```

Comment: we are here to help :D

Comment: You can listen for the keyup event and check if the user click the enter  key for example

Comment: Actually I am not very well in jquery or javascript, I want the textarea field more realtime like, when I type something in the input filed like any character may be, it should pass to the textarea in the same time, For now I have to click in the input filed 2 to make the input field value 1 passed to the textarea

Comment: Besides when I delete text from input field, its not deleting from the textarea

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var text1 = $('#text1');
  var text2 = $('#text2');
  var description = $('#description');

  function onChange() {
    description.val("Chesis No:  " + text1.val() + ", Engine No:  " + text2.val());

    var base = description.val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + base, "i");
    $('#description').on("input", function(ev) {
      var query = $(this).val();
      
    });
  }

  $('#text1')
    .change(onChange)
    .keyup(onChange);

  $('#text2')
    .change(onChange)
    .keyup(onChange);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Chassis No" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="Engine No " class="form-control" />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="postContent" id="description"></textarea>
```

Comment: But I want the textarea content(obtained from two input field) readonly, besides i can type extra things to the textarea.

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: I am waiting , Thanksss